# How have the "following trig formulas" been modified to obtain the new trig formulas?

Tags: trigonometry

I was reading a trig book in which the author had deduced the following formulas from a drawing. I am mentioning those as follows...

[image]

By looking at the above drawing the author deduced these formulas for $(\theta+90^\circ)$...

**1. $\sin (\theta + 90^\circ)=\cos\theta$**

**2. $\cos (\theta + 90^\circ)=-\sin\theta$**

**3. $\tan (\theta + 90^\circ)=-\cot\theta$**

I understood how did he conclude above formulas from the drawing.

As you can see the drawing depicts author's approach to derive the $(\theta+90^\circ)$ formulas by taking a similar triangle in the second quadrant, in the same way, to derive $(\theta-90^\circ)$ formulas, he advised to take a similar triangle (as in the drawing) in quadrant 4 as well. But, to the contrary he mentioned a trick to get those formulas which I do not understand.

The author told to replace $\theta$ in formulas **1,2 and 3** by $(\theta-90^\circ)$. So what I got by doing that is...

**1. $\sin ((\theta-90^\circ) + 90^\circ)=\cos(\theta-90^\circ)$**

**2. $\cos ((\theta-90^\circ) + 90^\circ)=-\sin(\theta-90^\circ)$**

**3. $\tan ((\theta-90^\circ) + 90^\circ)=-\cot(\theta-90^\circ)$**

By evaluating them further I get...

**1. $\sin (\theta)=\cos(\theta-90^\circ)$** (I got this one correct)

**2. $\cos (\theta)=-\sin(\theta-90^\circ)$** (wrong)

**3. $\tan (\theta)=-\cot(\theta-90^\circ)$** (wrong)

But the author says that the outcome of the formulas should be...

**1.$\sin (\theta)=\cos(\theta-90^\circ)$** (correct.)

**2. $-\cos (\theta)=\sin(\theta-90^\circ)$**

**3. $\tan (\theta-90^\circ) =-\cot(\theta)$**

I don't know where am I going wrong. The author told to replace $\theta$ by $(\theta-90^\circ)$ then why am I getting my answers incorrect? Where is the flaw? Please help me to track it down.

Comment: Just because you don't get the exact character-for-character representation of the equation, doesn't mean you did it wrong. For example, the (2) that you have is equivalent to the (2) the author has. Can you see why?

Comment: The $-$ sign is on opposite sides in both those equations. How is it correect?  I can't see why.

Comment: @SakshamSharma Assume $u=-v$. Multiply both sides by $(-1)$ to obtain $-u=v$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I understood. Your convention holds true for $2$. What about the last one? $3$?

Comment: Well, you have $\tan(\mathrm{thing}) = -\cot(\mathrm{other thing})$. What do you know about $\tan(\mathrm{other thing})$ and $\cot(\mathrm{thing})$?

Comment: @HenrySwansonDo I have to use $1/tanx=cotx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, for equation **2** it is simple. Assume you have..

$u=-v$ then you can get $-u=v$  by multiplying the equation on both sides by $-1$.

For **3**, use the reciprocal identity...$$\tan(x)=\frac{1}{\cot(x)}$$

and substitute it in the respective variables to arrive at the desired answer.